# Ui switch in datatable in angular

Tags: angular, datatable, uiswitch

I am new in angular and i'm working on making a datable with ui switch for every row to change the state of each one (true or false) ,when i click on the first switch (row1) it changes it's state but when i click on the second switch (row2) it changes also the 1st one not the second ,
Please help me

```js
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import {SiteService} from '../../site/site.service';
import {ModalDismissReasons, NgbModal} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms';
import {Ligne} from '../../../model/ligne';
import {Device} from '../../../model/device';
const Swal = require('sweetalert2');

@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-alldevice',
  templateUrl: './alldevice.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./alldevice.component.scss']})
export class AlldeviceComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private service: SiteService,
              private modalService: NgbModal, private router: Router,
              private form: FormBuilder) { }

  closeResult: string;
  devurl = 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/devices/updateDevice/';
  private device: Device[];
  public data: Array<Device>;
  public data1;
  public final;
  public item;
  state: boolean;
  ok = this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/devices/findbyuser').subscribe(data => {
    const resSTR = JSON.stringify(data);
    const resJSON = JSON.parse(resSTR);
    this.data = resJSON;
    this.data1 = data;
    
 onChange(event, code) {
    console.log('OnChange: ' + event) ;
    console.log('code: ' + code) ;
    this.http.patch('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/devices/updateStatebycode/' + code,
      {state: event} ).
    subscribe(data => { console.log(event); });
  }}
```

```html
 <table class="table table-striped table-hover" >
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Code</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Ligne</th>
          <th>Longitude</th>
          <th>Latitude</th>
          <th>Light Status</th>
          <th>Actions</th>
        </tr></thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let hero of data1">
          <td>{{hero.code}}</td>
          <td>{{hero.name}}</td>
          <td>{{hero.ligneName}}</td>
          <td>{{hero.lng}}</td>
          <td>{{hero.lat}}</td>
          <td>
            <ui-switch size="medium" [checked]="hero.state" (change)="onChange($event,hero.code)" ></ui-switch>
          </td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
         </table>
```

Comment: Can you post your code so we can see what you've tried so far?

Comment: @herondale i edited the post u can check it